# Inputting time in the form HHMM in python

Tags: python, time, token

I want to input a time in the form HHMM to one of my programs in Python but when I do, I get

```
"SyntaxError: invalid token",
```

I think this is because it is not a valid octal number, as I have seen on other websites, [for example](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081230215833AACOoBu).

The code I'm using is:

```
time1 = float(input("Please enter time 1:"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to convert your string to an actual datetime object, which has lots of useful methods:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input('specify time in HHMM format: '), "%H%M")
specify time in HHMM format: 0830
>>> time
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 30)
>>> time.time()
datetime.time(8, 30)
>>> time.hour
8
```

Using Python2.7 here (hence: [`raw_input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)).

The `SyntaxError` you're observing is also explained by that link: you're using `input`, rather than `raw_input` in Python2.x.

Comment: Thank you ... I'll have a go!